# WebBrowser control from ATL to c#

Tags: c#, c++, com, windows-mobile, atl

In ATL if I create webbrowser control using `IWebBrowser2`, it works great in Windows Mobile. I am able to visit all sites, progress bar comes, everything is fine..
rest of UI content I can't do in ATL, since it's time consuming. I would like to go for c#.
can any one suggest me how to make ATL activex control and use it in c#.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to create the IWebBrowser2 active X control in the CF without a very, very, very large amount of work.  I'd guess it to be a couple weeks even if you know how to do COM interop with the CF (which is not easy nor fun).

What may be a simpler route is to use the native control wrapped in htmlview.dll.  The easiest way to get there is to first download the free source code for version 1.4 of the SDF ([the download is here, bottom middle of the page](http://opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx)) then look in OpenNETCF.Windows.Form\WebBrowser.cs for the code.